# React Nested Routes With In A Copoment Besides Main Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, nested-routes

I have 3 main pages like

```
/   
/signup
/dashboard  #on successfull login
```

The problem is that after login , user will be there on dashboard page `/dashboard` , The dashboard page has 2 main components

1. side navigation menu
2. inner Dashboard
   (divided the screen as two)

side nav has some links call users , organizations etc .
when user clicks on that menu i want to display

```
 /dashboard/user , /dashboard/organisations
```

in inner dashboard without affecting the headers and side nav
**My App.Js File**

```
 // Main App.js(Route file of react project)

<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Login}/>
      <Route path="/signup" exact component={Signup}/>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
     </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

How Can I do that? Any Ideas . Thanks In Advance

Comment: to clarify, your user is a user id or the text "user"? do you want to display both `<User/>` and `<Organisations/>` under dashboard when a link is clicked in side navigation menu?

Comment: actually i need /user/:id bt for test purpose i tried with /user...when user is clicked inner dashboard should show User component and when Organisation is clicked it should show organisation component in inner dashboard..not both at a time

Comment: First you would need to add an optional parameter to your dashboard path => path="/dashboard/:route" (replace ":route" with your preferred name). Then in the dashboard you can get the 'route' parameter from props.match.params.route.

Comment: Can you show the Link tags you are using to navigate from your side menu?

Comment: <Link to="/dashboard/organisation">Organisation</Link>                                                <Link to="/dashboard/user">User</Link>

Comment: @jpmarks   when user click on user tab the url will be /dashboard/user so as you told in inner dashboard i write                                      {props.match.params.route==="organisaion" && <Organisation/>}                             so it works !!!! Thank You So much for the idea, however am still looking for if i can do it with normal routes

Comment: Why do you want to do it with normal routes? If you define both routes or have one varibale parameter, doesnt make much of a difference if you are trying to reuse the same component and page.